# How can i have a page with a Iframe/Html5 Video and a Read More Button whose src and href value can be changed with the help of javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, video, iframe, html5-video

I have a page on my site(blogger) on which I want to have multiple video/iframes and a button for more info about the videos. But having so many videos/iframes on one page may impact the site's SEO and Loading Time and also the look.

So I want to have only one video/iframe and a Read More button on the page with more navigation links below it for easy navigation to other videos.

Here's my Code:

```
<!-- if there's a video -->
<video id="video-id">
<source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<!-- if there's an iframe -->
<iframe class="responsive-video" src="" allowfullscreen scrolling="no" allow="encrypted-media">
<button class="read-more" href="">Know More About This</button>
<hr style="opacity:0.2;">
<button class="btn-class" href="#" data-video="https://site.xyz/video-src.mp4" data-btn="https://site2.xyz/btn-href/">Video 1</button>
<!-- And Other Buttons Like This -->
```

Can you please tell Me the javascript that can be uses in this case. Also I'm new to javascript, so please be specific in your answer.

Thanks.

Comment: `<center>` is obsolete. `<button>` with `href` is invalid. Where's the `<iframe>`, moreover, what is the purpose of said `<iframe>`>? Also, if you ask for JavaScript, show some JavaScript. Read about the required [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake that i added `<center>` and also the `<button>` you are asking I wanted to add `<a>` to make it look like the readmore button but I added `<button>`. And also because I was busy I skipped the Iframe but the iframe should come in the video's place. And thanks for sharing the "minimal reproducible example" because I'm new to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the src of video and href on anchor on click of the button 'Video 1'

```js
function playVideo() {
  //Change video src
  document.getElementById("video-id").src = event.target.getAttribute('data-video')

  //Change anchor's href
  document.getElementById("read-more-btn").href = event.target.getAttribute('data-btn')

}
```

```css
.read-more {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<video id="video-id">
  <source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div class="read-more">
  <a id="read-more-btn" href="">Know More About This</a>
</div>
<hr style="opacity:0.2;">
<button class="btn-class" onclick="playVideo()" href="#" data-video='https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4' data-btn="https://site2.xyz/btn-href/" data-video="">Video 1</button>
<!-- And Other Buttons Like This -->
```